# How to optimize ABAP query

Tags: sql, abap

I have a query which appears to be working fine, but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner (or more proper) way to write it.

The goal is to find the record in table ZVBAPIUSW01 where the date (UPDPASS) and time (UPDPASSTIME) are the greatest based on a given user ID.

Here is what I have got so far:

```
SELECT SINGLE * FROM ZVBAPIUSW01
  WHERE OBJID = ID
  AND UPDPASS IN (
    SELECT MAX( UPDPASS ) FROM ZVBAPIUSW01 WHERE OBJID = ID )
  AND UPDPASSTIME IN (
    SELECT MAX( UPDPASSTIME ) FROM ZVBAPIUSW01 WHERE OBJID = ID AND UPDPASS IN (
      SELECT MAX( UPDPASS ) FROM ZVBAPIUSW01 WHERE OBJID = ID ) ).
```

Thanks for your help.
Mike

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try

```
SELECT foo bar baz
  FROM ZVBAPIUSW01 UP TO 1 ROWS
  INTO (l_foo, l_bar, l_baz)
  WHERE OBJID = ID
  ORDER BY updpass DESCENDING updpasstime DESCENDING.
```

Comment: Thank you. This is such a simple (and obvious) way to get what I'm looking for. I will switch SELECT foo bar baz with SELECT SINGLE * as I want all fields and in ABAP, the single keyword gives me only the first record from the result set.

Comment: I'm sorry you can't use SELECT SINGLE with ORDER BY, you should use vwegert syntax.

Comment: You are correct franblay, SINGLE and ORDER BY cannot be used together. I will have to find another way. However, this will work in other places or if I simply just look at the first returned record, so I will accept this answer.

Comment: The UP TO 1 ROWS completes this answer for me.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Select * instead use Select (required list)

Comment: Yes, good point.  That will provide some minor optimization, but I'm wondering if I should be performing the sub 'selects' in a different manner.

Comment: Joins are better means of getting what you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979927/how-can-i-join-a-table-to-itself-in-t-sql

Comment: Note that JOINs override the SAP database cache. There is, however, a workaround. When you query a database view based on your join, you can enable caching for it.